# How do I remove HTTPS results from Google after the domain has been redirected and the SSL certificate taken down?

Tags: https, security-certificate

I need to remove HTTPS results from Google search rankings for the domain A that has been redirected to another domain B. So domain A does not have any pages on it at the moment and it will not have in the future. Customers still go to Google and type company domain A, Google gives them HTTPS version of it as SSL certificate was installed at some point in the past. When they click on it (HTTPS version), redirection does not work as I can't redirect HTTPS but only HTTP.

So how do I remove or ask Google to remove HTTPS version? My client does not know whether HTTPS site was submitted through webmaster tools before and does not have any Gmail accounts for me to check what has happened in the past.

Answer (score 4):

You can redirect the HTTPS version - you just need to have an SSL certificate for that domain.

Since the HTTPS version is what has apparently been indexed by Google, you'd be better off just setting up a certificate for that on your server and redirecting directly from that to the new domain. Not only would that save you an extra redirect step, it's also the more secure option as you avoid bouncing user between secure/validated & insecure connections.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew,
I was thinking about creating SSL certificate but I thought I will not be able to redirect https. So I will create domain on my hosting, point to my hosting at the level of registrar, get SSL and then redirect https on the level of my hosting. Did I get it right?

Comment: @Baben Sounds right to me!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use Cloudflare. Just set up the old domain in Cloudflare (using their DNS), then use [Page Rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427) with the Forwarding option. They provide free SSL (TLS) so there would be even less server config to worry about on your end.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to update your xml sitemap than update it in webmaster tools so that Google, Bing & Yahoo will index your website without HTTPS.

This way when Google index your website next time it will show your domain without HTTPS.